# iOS app update Vs Xcode run the app

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have an app in app store with version 1.0 and the app does not include storyboard.
Now I have added storyboard to my app and when I run it :

1) If I don't have the app in my device everything is ok and app runs successfully.

2) If the the previos version of app from app store is pre-installed in my device, and I run from the Xcode version 1.1 the app run with bug in UI.

what am I doing wrong ?

**edit 3.7.16 :**

after I try to upload to testFlight the bug still alive )-:
what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

It must be the build issue problem . Please go to the project -> General -> Dont change the build, leave it as it was. Change the version to 1.1 and then upload to appstore . everything will be fine then

Comment: why I see that when run in Xcode ? i try in release and debug and its still have the ui problem.

Comment: Is warning coming from Storyboard ??

Comment: if it is coming from storyboard then it is a formal error and nothing will happen when you release the app, I too got the error but releived when i build in the appstore

Comment: after I try to upload to testFlight the bug still alive )-:

Comment: check out the certificates ... if any certificate issue it may show the error